# Changing arrangement of square's vertices with a bijective continuous map in plane.

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, discrete-geometry

Is there a continuous bijective map $S:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ which convert vertices of Square $ABCD$ (respectly arranged points) to vertices of Square $A'C'B'D'$ ? 
(each points goes to its prime)

Comment: Yes. In fact there is a continuous map that takes any $k$ points to any other $k$ points. You can even make it bijective.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip In fact I was meaning a bijective continuous map but I forgot to write it . How bijective it can be?

Comment: You can do this with an affine map (even better: You can do this with an affine map preserving angles - once you get three points, the last one comes for free!) That's way stronger than just continuous bijection.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: note the cyclic order of the vertices has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there is a simpler argument, but you can use the isotopy extension theorem for this. Find some isotopy that moves the given points in the plane (in this case $A,B,C,D$) to the new points you want.  This then extends to an ambient isotopy of the plane, and in particular gives you a homeomorphism.

Comment: That's right .we can find a simple continuous bijection map to substitude $B$ and $C$ and let $A$ and $D$ be constant. Now the problem I think about is what's the optimal continuous bijection map which changes the least to $\mathbb{R^2}$  points in order to substitute $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @MasM The map I mentioned will leave most of the plane fixed. It will just be nontrivial in a neighborhood of the arcs that guide the isotopy. You can make these neighborhoods as small as you want. Of course the formula for the map will be very messy.

Answer (score 2):

In order to simple the question we just need to replace $B$ and $C$ and let $A$ and $D$ fixed. Now consider an annuli contains $B$ and $C$ on two side of a diameter of mid circle of the annuli,the map rotates points on each concentric circles of the annuli by gradually increasing angles between $(0,2\pi)$ when radius of the circles goes bigger, eventually $B$ and $C$ which lie on the mid circle of the annuli rotates $\pi$ and substitute eachother.here we just moved points in the annuli and the other points remains fixed.

Comment: @Cheerful Parsnip can we find better optimal map than this?

Comment: Nice answer! $\phantom{.}$